# Ubuntu does not see second (first?) monitor (video card?)

Tags: 16.04, multiple-monitors, gpu-driver

I have installed Ubuntu onto my computer with 2 monitors. One monitor is connected to processor video via `VGA` cable, another one -- to discrete Nvidia card via `DVI` cable.

Computer is dual boot and `Windows` sees both monitors and extends desktop on them.

Latter one is working, and there are no traces of former one.

Is it possible to force this thing to find all monitors / video cards I have?

**UPDATE**

I have downloaded Intel Graphics tool and ran it's update feature, but got

[image]

Before that I went to System Settings | Software & Updates | Additional Drivers and achieved that second device turned from "not working" to this:

[image]

Unfortunately, Ubuntu forgot to say me what this device is and it can be something different, than graphics card...

**UPDATE 2**

When I tried to install that lib, it said:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libglapi-mesa
[sudo] password for dims: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libglapi-mesa is already the newest version (17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).
```

**UPDATE 3**

I bypassed the problem with package mismatch, but still don't see second video card.

**UPDATE 4**

```
$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
    Kernel modules: i915
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1b81 (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device 3302
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_375_drm, nvidia_375
```

**UPDATE 5**

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DVI-D-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: No, it is not possible to use the cards simultaneously and most BIOS/UEFI automatically disable the integrated one if a discrete is detected.

Comment: I am using them simultaneously in Windows. So Ubuntu has this limitation?

Comment: It's mostly a drivers' limitation.

Comment: @MichaelBay That is wrong. On desktops both cards can be used.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: The drivers look OK. How is the non-working monitor connected? Is there some adapter? And also please add output of `xrandr`.

Comment: @Pilot6 see my `update 5` please, also I have specified cables in the preamble (`VGA` + `DVI`)

Comment: @Pilot6 non working is monitor, connected via `VGA` to built-in graphics.